# Can I upgrade and downgrade between Windows 10 and Windows 7 at will?

Tags: windows-10

I know I have a year to upgrade. But I am thinking about how portable this upgrade is. 
1) If install the upgrade and then reinstall my previous windows, can I upgrade to Windows 10 again??
2) Same question but AFTER the period of free windows 10 is up and implying I upgraded initially before the period.

Can I upgrade and downgrade between Windows 10 and Windows 7 at will? I have my original Windows 7 disk and registration code.

Comment: You have a year to get the free upgrade, you have 30 days to revert to previous W7, no it cannot go on for more than 30 days. If you make a system image of the Windows 7 install that is Activated (using 3rd party image software), then you could re-image the drive at any time and have W7 again, but if it ever checks the W7 key again it will deactivate as the W10 install deactivates the W7 key after 30 days, this info is stored on the Microsoft servers with your hardware profile.

Comment: Hmmm, then I may not upgrade. Do you have any proof of this? If you do, I'd give you the answer for this.

Comment: @Moab - Are you saying that once you use a W7 or W8 key to update to W10, you can never use that key to downgrade? No downgrade rights?

Comment: I read somewhere that pirated copies of windows can upgrade to Windows 10......so this means people with pirated copies can get a free windows 10 but people with legitimate older versions lose their copy? I really hope this is not the case.

Comment: @AlexS. According to Microsoft downgrade rights expire 30 days after W10 is installed.

Comment: @munchschair, yes you can upgrade to W10 from pirate version but will Never activate.

Comment: @Moab - I posted this on another forum and the downgrade rights seem to be not conclusive as yet.

Answer (score 0):

After the upgrade Windows10, if you do not like it, you can go back and choose to downgrade it to windows 7, but Microsoft has mentioned that the Rollback operating is available for a month only, after which, the files required for this operation, will be deleted. That means, during this time, if you do not deleted the **$Windows.~BT and $Windows.~WS folders** required by the system to perform the rollback operation. Of course, you can choose to back windows 10 again.

If it’s been over a month — or if you’ve run the DIsk cleanup tool and removed the “Previous Windows installations” files or deleted the C:\Windows.old folder by hand — you’ll no longer see this option. Windows 10 appears to automatically remove the old Windows installation files after a month to free up space. Then you can only have the opportunity to downgrade by rollback tool like [Easeus System GoBack](http://www.easeus.com/system-go-back/). The downgrade tool is no time limit, EaseUS released the free program for Windows that claims to do exactly that.

**Note:** The program is only of use if you run it prior to upgrading to Windows 10 (or any other system for that matter). If you get a system running Windows 10, or want to downgrade without having created a backup first using the program or another one, then you won't be able to go back using third-party software.

Comment: Can you improve the answer? 
PS: Try this out and see if it works. 
Also, backup the folders etc that are set to auto delete after a month. Insert it back after a month (or forwarded date) / backward date and let us know if that can be done?

Comment: So, the rollback feature expires only through microsoft? My question is if the license does. I have the original disks and codes.